# Detect if filesystem supports FIEMAP ioctl

Tags: linux, filesystems, ioctl

How can I query the kernel to find out if a mounted filesystem supports the FIEMAP ioctl? Is there a way to request the `inode_operations` struct for a given filesystem?

As a workaround, I just test the FIEMAP ioctl on a random file, but this seems fragile - not every file is supported even when the filesystem *does* support it in general (directories, etc.).